# Network Bonding for Stability, not Connection Strength/Speed

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, bonding

## The Overall Concept:

So, I had this nifty idea/concept for a "device" that would give you consistent access to the internet, even if your connection was constantly and frequently changing.

## The "Device":

The "device" is a small network (you can carry it in a backpack or purse) of tethered mobile devices connected to either a cheap laptop or a raspberry pi. Since changing wireless connections is somewhat of a slow process, I had the idea of using parallel processing to "speed" it up.

## The Example Problem:

Let's say I'm walking down Jane St. There's a McDonald's, some homes that have setup guest networks, a hotel, and a school, and the wireless connections being broadcasted from these locations are public and they are equidistant from each other in a line. Let's say while I am walking, I have no cellular data, I need to download my eBook for classes, it's going to take some time, and I care very little for my own network security.

## My Solution/Breakdown of How "Device" Works:

What my "device" would do is have one or more of it's mobile devices establish wireless connections, then another mobile device would be told to change it's wireless connection. Once the change has been made, the next mobile device in the chain is told to change it's wireless connection if needed (weak connection detected). While this is ongoing, all devices are tethered to a central computer, say an old IBM thinkbrick or a rapsberry pi. The objective is to make sure that the thinkbrick or raspberry pi has a constant network connection, or at least if the connection goes down, it's right back up in less than seconds.

## Too Long; Didn't Read:

The issue here is that, since the connection to an ISP is constantly changing, and there are multiple connections to different ISPs going on at once, that tends to "break things" being performed by the central computer/IBM Thinkbrick/Raspberry Pi.

Is there a way to prevent that or at the least reduce that problem (like network bonding)?

## Additional Problem-Unrelated Concept Information:

Since the devices controlling the connections to the outside network are mobile devices, I intend to set them up to change network connection based on location as well. If a location has been known by the network to have good reliable connections, then the mobile devices in that network will attempt to connect to those connections first.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe DDNS could work...not sure how to implement it though

Comment: Google searching came back with multi-wan routers. Trying to find a way to implement multi-wan without a router or using a pseudo-router

Comment: Came across openwrt's mwan3. I think it could do the trick...

Comment: The multi-WAN routers I’ve come across are big rack-mounted, enterprise affairs. Draytek do a smaller home office type one too. What they all have in common is that none of them are portable and they all have some kind of proprietary software/firmware to handle all the magic. Not sure is there’s any kind of FOSS package that can do this. Your hypothetical device would also require one network device for each network you’d want to connect to. I think a better option would be the equivalent of a multi-SIM phone where the phone can use one of two different networks based on availability.

Comment: @Darren Extensive google research had me stumble across this: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=145919; suggesting that it is possible

Comment: Simply running a VPN with stable ips and a default toute over it would get you 80percent of the way, as most of the problems are caused by changing IP addresses and the resulting timeouts and loss of tcp stream.  Even if you do implement a milti-connection solution you will want to bond the connections using a VPN/tunnel to ensure stable IP addressing.

Comment: @davidgo I will be looking at that when I have the chance

Comment: @Darren Also, as to your point of multi-SIM phone, where the phone can use one of 2 networks. The point of multi-phone as opposed to multi-sim has to do with cost. I can get cheap used android phones for less than $10, and having more than one phone can allow for a lot more things to get done. Not necessarily only connecting to networks.